# How to install Android plugin into the Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, android, linux, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

How do you install NetBeans IDE the Android plugin? Is this link working or any alternative? http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/pages/Install

When i try i get failure:

[image]
[image]

```
Also this gives failure: http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/directory/archives  or http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/archives/nbandroid-dev-2011-11-10_13-25-27.zip

SERVER ERROR

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

Comment: just wait and try tomorrow. I've installed it a couple of days ago and it was the same link you posted.

Comment: @hovanessyan: You mean one of those? http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/archives/nbandroid-dev-2011-11-10_13-25-27.zip

Comment: I am pretty sure I've installed it from the zip, but I just found an alternative - using the update center in Netbeans: http://www.nbandroid.org/p/installation.html. @MikeLentini I've installed NetBeans just to use the UML reverse-engineering plugin - it's the best out there :D.

Comment: @hovanessyan: thanks just added but same error. Will try later after hours or so.

Comment: @hovanessyan: it asking more, plz see above second screen shot.

Comment: Nevermind, its working today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Netbeans for my JAVA project before, but when I started with Android I found it more useful to start with Eclipce. So if you not have to use NB, I recommend you to switch.

Comment: I am doing C,Bash, Zend Framework, Jquery, Html, Java. + Jut now i need Android, i cant switch with all toys just for one Droid!

Answer (score 1):

Kenai.com site no longer hosts these plugins. I recommend going to Install Plugins..|Settings | Add (Give it a name e.g. Android or NB)|Ok  http://nbandroid.org/updates/updates.xml or if you're having a lazy connection download the plugins directly from http://nbandroid.org/downloads/ and add them from the Download tab and proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Android common library, 
Android Core,  Android Ddmlib, 
AndroidPrefs, Android Project
SDK Library,
first only install these and then go for next it will work!!